# The best practice to count characters from back in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a Python string like this:

`url = "https://github.com/websanova/boilerplate/archive/master.zip"`

And to extract the documentation URL, I will have to remove 18 characters from back which corresponds to `archive/master.zip` so that I get this `https://github.com/websanova/boilerplate/`

So I did this:

`documentation = url[:len(url)-18]`

But something is telling me that's not the right way. I would like to know which is the best practice.

And .. I am using Py-V3.x

Comment: Do you want the code to work for any `url`? Or do all `url`s end in `archive/master.zip`? _I have no idea of git._

Comment: All URLs end with archive/master.zip at least if I am pulling from master branch

Comment: Simple regex for extracting the user and repo name from the url: `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www.)?github\.com\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\/`.

Comment: @fredrick by the way  I was talking about all strings in general not just this URL And PS: I don't know what italics mean but if it is Sarcasm I don't like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url[:-18]` is sufficient. Negative indexes start at the len(str) automatically:

```
>>> url = "https://github.com/websanova/boilerplate/archive/master.zip"
>>> url[:-18]
'https://github.com/websanova/boilerplate/'
```

That being said, I wouldn't recommend using a set value... instead, I'd suggest something like:

`url[:url.rfind('/', 0, url.rfind('/')) + 1]`

which will strip off the filename and one folder, regardless of the length of each string:

```
url[:                                 + 1]  # slice the string, ending at
     url.rfind('/', 0,              )  # the last occurrence of / in the substring ending
                      url.rfind('/')  # on the last / (so exluding it)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
url = "https://github.com/websanova/boilerplate/archive/master.zip"
url = url[:-18]
```

Instead you can also use this:

```
url = "https://github.com/websanova/boilerplate/archive/master.zip"
url = url.replace("archive/master.zip","")
```